# How can I get content of div that is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to get the content of one clicked div on click event?

```
<div class="chosen">a</div>
<div class="chosen">b</div>
<div class="chosen">c</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".chosen").click(function(){

    //???

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want text

```
$(".chosen").click(function(){
     var content = $(this).text();
});
```

If you want all contents(HTML elements and text nodes)

```
$(".chosen").click(function(){
     var content = $(this).contents();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
$(".chosen").click(function(){
    var cntnt = $(this).html();
});
```

Note that this returns the content of the FIRST matched element.